# How to rewrite nginx rule to htacces rule?

Tags: apache, nginx

How I can rewrite this rule from nginx config to apache?

```
location /bower_components {
    alias /var/www/keepcalm/html/bower_components;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need add following code to config of virtual host

```
AliasMatch "^/bower_components/(.*)$" "/var/www/keepcalm2/html/bower_components/$1"
```